# Rewrite php code - check if date is between 2 dates to check if date is between months

Tags: php

I have a yearly recurrent event that starts in May and ends in September. How would I rewrite this to check if a date is in a range of month?

Here is my working code - but I have to manually change the year every year

`$queryDate` is set by a Datepicker

```
<?php
$startDate = strtotime("05/01/20");
$endDate   = strtotime("09/30/20");

$comparisonDate = $queryDate;   
$comparisonDate = strtotime($comparisonDate);

    if($startDate <= $comparisonDate && $comparisonDate <= $endDate)
    {
        echo 'OK';
    }else{
        echo 'NO';  
    }
?>
```

Have found this small code that seems to be able solve the issue - but I can't figure how to make it check for multiple month or (d/m). And if possible a specific date in a month like (d/m) between 05/May to 25/Sep

```
<?php
$date = "2019-11-30";
if(date("m", strtotime($date)) == date("11"))
 {
    echo 'ok';
 }else{
    echo 'no';
 }
?>
```

All clues or solutions are highly appreciated

Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185249/1213708 seems to do the part of setting the dates to the current year, then the comparison should be straightforward.

Comment: I would also recommend using 4 digit years as `05/01/20` can be more ambiguous than `05/01/2020`

Comment: `date()` and `strtotime()` and the other date & time functions are old and clumsy. Use the [`DateTime` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) and its friends. They are easier to use and can be compared directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform this string to the DateTime datatype, which allows you to make any further comparing:

```
$startDate = strtotime("05/01");
$endDate   = strtotime("09/30");

$start1 = date('m/d', $startDate);
$end1 = date('m/d', $endDate);

$st_date = new DateTime($start1);
//   echo $st_date->format('m/d/y').PHP_EOL;
$end_date = new DateTime($end1);
//   echo $end_date->format('m/d/y').PHP_EOL;
```

Your input datepicker string has other datetime mask `Y-m-d`:

```
$comparisonDate = "2020-06-30";
$comparisonDate = strtotime($comparisonDate); 

$cmp1 = date('Y-m-d', $comparisonDate);
$cmp_date = new DateTime($cmp1);
$dtp_year = $cmp_date->format('y');
//   echo $cmp_date->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
```

And here you can define the current year:

```
$cur_date = new DateTime();
$cur_year = $cur_date->format('y');
```

With this stuff you will receive desired result from `if statement`:

```
if($st_date <= $cmp_date && $cmp_date <= $end_date && $cur_year == $dtp_year)
{
    echo 'OK';
}else{
    echo 'NO';  
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/moIZL)**

Answer (score 0):

Time to move to more up-to-date methods, which allow to compare dates easily:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('05/01 this year');
$endDate   = new DateTime("09/30 this year");

$curDate = new DateTime();  // will give you current date

var_dump($curDate > $startDate && $curDate < $endDate);
```

More about `datetime` (including formats) is in [manual](https://www.php.net/datetime).

Answer (score 0):

if u want to make this code dynamic then just convert the date for to numeric months

```
$comparisonDate = strtotime("04/30/20");
$eventDate=(int)date('m',$comparisonDate); //the date return string which is converted as int

if($eventDate >= 5 & $eventDate <= 9 ){echo "success";}
```